# AsyncTestCompleter Browserify Angular2 HTTP Mock Test

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular, karma-runner

I am about to get started with Angular 2 tests, I am pretty new to Angular 2 and got stuck with testing.

I am following the testing guide:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html

```
    > TimesheetCrusher@0.0.5 test C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "karma start karma.conf.js"

[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.801:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining framework:jasmine).
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.807:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining launcher:Chrome, launcher:ChromeCanary, launcher:Dartium, test).
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.808:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining reporter:html).
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.808:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining bro, framework:browserify, preprocessor:browserify, preprocessor:browserify-bundle, preprocess).
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.808:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining launcher:Chrome_travis_ci).
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.823:DEBUG [framework.browserify]: created browserify bundle: C:\Users\Toby\AppData\Local\Temp\a3ebde98982e7b28c9d1624786c469a4.browserify
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.856:DEBUG [framework.browserify]: no matching preprocessed file was found, defaulting to prepend
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.857:DEBUG [framework.browserify]: add bundle to config.files at position 0
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.875:DEBUG [web-server]: Instantiating middleware
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.907:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load reporter: html
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.909:DEBUG [reporter]: Trying to load color-version of reporter: html (html_color)
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:27.909:DEBUG [reporter]: Couldn't load color-version.
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:29.104:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/systemjs.config.extras.js" does not match any file.
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:29.118:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/dist/src/**/*.html" does not match any file.
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:29.123:WARN [watcher]: Pattern "C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/dist/src/**/*.css" does not match any file.
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:29.522:DEBUG [framework.browserify]: building bundle
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:29.921:DEBUG [framework.browserify]: updating dist\test\backand\backand-rest.service.spec.js in bundle
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:30.627:DEBUG [framework.browserify]: bundling
[0] 9:11:30 AM - Compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.762:ERROR [framework.browserify]: bundle error
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.762:ERROR [framework.browserify]: 
[1] C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\@angular\core\testing\async_test_completer.js:11
[1] export var AsyncTestCompleter = (function () {
[1] ^
[1] ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.800:WARN [karma]: Port 9876 in use
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.801:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.3.0 server started at http://localhost:9877/
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.802:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.833:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.833:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at C:\Users\Toby\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-98045299
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.834:DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\Toby\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-98045299 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-default-apps --disable-popup-blocking --disable-translate --disable-background-timer-throttling http://localhost:9877/?id=98045299
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.249:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\karma\static/client.html
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.278:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\karma\static/karma.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.463:DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket /#xhFGIxQD4-dw1xNtAAAA
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.467:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\karma\static/favicon.ico
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.483:DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xhFGIxQD4-dw1xNtAAAA
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.484:DEBUG [proxy]: NOT upgrading proxyWebSocketRequest /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xhFGIxQD4-dw1xNtAAAA
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.524:INFO [Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#xhFGIxQD4-dw1xNtAAAA with id 98045299
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.525:DEBUG [launcher]: Chrome (id 98045299) captured in 1.722 secs
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.544:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: custom files null null
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.544:DEBUG [middleware:karma]: Serving static request /context.html
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.557:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\karma\static/context.html
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.571:DEBUG [web-server]: serving: C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\karma\static/context.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.583:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /absoluteC:/Users/Toby/AppData/Local/Temp/a3ebde98982e7b28c9d1624786c469a4.browserify?59c06c9eba4f4adc27dc229cfaebba395247ee16 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.583:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/AppData/Local/Temp/a3ebde98982e7b28c9d1624786c469a4.browserify
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.585:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/AppData/Local/Temp/a3ebde98982e7b28c9d1624786c469a4.browserify
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.589:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js?945a38bf4e45ad2770eb94868231905a04a0bd3e /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.589:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.590:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js?1e4f995124c2f01998fd4f3e16ace577bf155ba9 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.590:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.592:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js?ce47c157d0451bc324d5039dfc7b04fa1cf0925d /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.593:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.595:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js?391e45351df9ee35392d2e5cb623221a969fc009 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.595:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.595:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js?23bcf04b0fcefe4c6fe3d641e6c1c6fd2a525332 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.595:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.596:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/boot.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.597:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.598:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.601:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.603:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.607:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js?dda56e9eda58525388f2f12f0e03222eea4db7ec /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.608:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.608:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?c35727d0e64913b5669320b167e496fc94fc6928 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.609:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.609:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js?190d11155f82a27dfb07231dd5d843be81752df0 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.609:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.611:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.612:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.614:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.615:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js?13037d720197b33695136adbb068be1826fe1bda /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.615:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.616:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js?e9499c7853b5f42755015c38ee71b41d2b3a4c2a /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.616:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.619:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.626:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.629:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js?18f8bcddbcafc03a52e8f190726a85581b4a3c10 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.629:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.631:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js?dfbb53d215a0f5fe064360706cf52ba5c0f40c30 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.632:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.632:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js?0337d6818a2aefcefb40ab4e513943f5ff3e9fb0 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.632:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.632:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/karma-test-shim.js?a8b46428653c0dfd7ef5d35dfe6b8633a9821984 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.633:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/karma-test-shim.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.635:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.638:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.639:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.646:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/karma-test-shim.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.647:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Requesting /base/dist/test/backand/backand-rest.service.spec.js?0d2f3c79f250240de04a539f2d50e1d95d102562 /
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.647:DEBUG [middleware:source-files]: Fetching C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/dist/test/backand/backand-rest.service.spec.js
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.649:DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): C:/Users/Toby/WebstormProjects/timesheetCrusher/dist/test/backand/backand-rest.service.spec.js
[1] Chrome 53.0.2785 (Windows 10 0.0.0) ERROR
[1]   Uncaught Error: bundle error (see logs)
[1]   at C:/Users/Toby/AppData/Local/Temp/a3ebde98982e7b28c9d1624786c469a4.browserify:1
[1] 
[1] 
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.683:DEBUG [karma]: Run complete, exiting.
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.720:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.721:DEBUG [framework.browserify]: cleaning up
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.789:ERROR [karma]: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined]
[1] TypeError: Cannot read property 'end' of undefined
[1]     at C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\karma-htmlfile-reporter\index.js:121:44
[1]     at C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\karma\lib\helper.js:144:7
[1]     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.838:DEBUG [launcher]: Disconnecting all browsers
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.838:DEBUG [framework.browserify]: cleaning up
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.933:DEBUG [launcher]: Process Chrome exited with code 0
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:33.934:DEBUG [temp-dir]: Cleaning temp dir C:\Users\Toby\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-98045299
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:34.039:DEBUG [launcher]: Finished all browsers
```

Here is the test:

```
import {BaseRequestOptions, Http, Response, BaseResponseOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import {ReflectiveInjector} from '@angular/core';
import {MockBackend} from '@angular/http/testing';
import {inject} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AsyncTestCompleter} from '@angular/core/testing/async_test_completer';

it('should get some data', inject([AsyncTestCompleter], (async) => {
  var connection;
  var injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
    MockBackend,
    {provide: Http, useFactory: (backend, options) => {
      return new Http(backend, options);
    }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]}]);
  var http = injector.get(Http);
  var backend = injector.get(MockBackend);
  //Assign any newly-created connection to local variable
  backend.connections.subscribe(c => connection = c);
  http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
    async.done();
  });
  var options = new BaseResponseOptions();
  var res = new Response(options.merge({
      body: 'awesome',
         headers: new Headers({framework: 'angular'})
  }));
  connection.mockRespond(res);
}));
```

The problem seems to be:

```
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.762:ERROR [framework.browserify]: bundle error
[1] 10 10 2016 09:11:31.762:ERROR [framework.browserify]: 
[1] C:\Users\Toby\WebstormProjects\timesheetCrusher\node_modules\@angular\core\testing\async_test_completer.js:11
[1] export var AsyncTestCompleter = (function () {
[1] ^
[1] ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module
```

'

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "TimesheetCrusher",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "description": "TimesheetCrusher",
  "scripts": {
    "typings-install": "typings install",
    "postinstall": "npm run typings-install",
    "build": "webpack --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "watch": "npm run build -- --watch",
    "server:dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached  --content-base src/",
    "server": "webpack-dev-server --inline --colors --progress --display-error-details --display-cached --port 3000  --content-base src",
    "start": "npm run server",
    "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "report": "lite-server -c bs-config.report.json",
    "clean": "rimraf public/* ",
    "cleanNodeModules" : "rimraf node_modules/*"
  },
  "contributors": [
    "Rob Wormald <robwormald@gmail.com>",
    "PatrickJS <github@gdi2290.com>"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "0.3.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "1.1.1",
    "browserify" : "13.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.8.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "1.1.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.0",
    "css-loader": "0.23.1",
    "es6-promise-loader": "1.0.1",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.2",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.1",
    "file-loader": "0.8.5",
    "http-server": "0.8.5",
    "imports-loader": "0.6.5",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "postcss-loader" : "0.10.1",
    "karma-browserify" : "5.1.0",
    "ncp": "2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "3.7.0",
    "phantomjs-polyfill": "0.0.1",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.4",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "resolve-url-loader": "1.4.3",
    "rimraf": "2.5.1",
    "sass-loader": "3.1.2",
    "source-map-loader": "0.1.5",
    "style-loader": "0.13.0",
    "ts-helper": "0.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "0.8.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tsconfig-lint": "0.5.0",
    "typedoc": "0.3.12",
    "typings": "1.0.4",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.12.13",
    "webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1",
    "webpack-md5-hash": "0.0.4",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.4.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-cli": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "protractor": "^3.3.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.2",
    "concurrently": "^2.2.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "0.5.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^1.9.0-dev",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.2",
    "bootstrap-loader": "1.0.9",
    "autoprefixer": "6.3.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.0.16",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "3.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.5.0",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.4.0",
    "simple-line-icons": "2.3.2",
    "glyphicons-halflings": "1.9.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",

    "jquery": "2.2.0",
    "tether": "1.1.1"

  },
  "keywords": [
    "Angular2",
    "angular2-seed",
    "official angular 2 seed",
    "official angular2 seed"
  ]
}
```

Here is the karma.conf.js:

```
// #docregion
module.exports = function (config) {

  var appBase = 'dist/src/';   // transpiled app JS and map files
  var appSrcBase = 'src/';       // app source TS files
  var appAssets = '/base/app/'; // component assets fetched by Angular's compiler

  var testBase = 'dist/test/'; // transpiled test JS and map files
  var testSrcBase = 'test/';      // test source TS files

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-htmlfile-reporter'),
      require('karma-browserify')
    ],

    customLaunchers: {
      // From the CLI. Not used here but interesting
      // chrome setup for travis CI using chromium
      Chrome_travis_ci: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: ['--no-sandbox']
      }
    },
    files: [
      // System.js for module loading
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js',

      // Polyfills
      'node_modules/core-js/client/shim.js',
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',

      // zone.js
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/sync-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',

      // RxJs
      {pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/rxjs/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      // Paths loaded via module imports:
      // Angular itself
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'node_modules/@angular/**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},

      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.js', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: 'systemjs.config.extras.js', included: false, watched: false},
      'karma-test-shim.js',

      // transpiled application & spec code paths loaded via module imports
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js', included: true, watched: true},


      // Asset (HTML & CSS) paths loaded via Angular's component compiler
      // (these paths need to be rewritten, see proxies section)
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.html', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.css', included: false, watched: true},

      // Paths for debugging with source maps in dev tools
      {pattern: appSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: appBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false},
      {pattern: testSrcBase + '**/*.ts', included: false, watched: true},
      {pattern: testBase + '**/*.js.map', included: false, watched: false}
    ],

    // Proxied base paths for loading assets
    proxies: {
      // required for component assets fetched by Angular's compiler
      "/app/": appAssets
    },

    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {
      'dist/test/**/*.spec.js': ['browserify']
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'html'],

    // HtmlReporter configuration
    htmlReporter: {
      // Open this file to see results in browser
      outputFile: 'test-output/tests.html',

      // Optional
      pageTitle: 'Unit Tests',
      subPageTitle: __dirname
    },

    // Browserify configuration
    browserify: {
      debug: true
    },

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: true
  })
}
```

So it seems browserify is having trouble with the Async test package.

The tooling around Angular 2 is massive and hard to get right at the beginning. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much.

Comment: it('...', async(inject([Http], (http) => {
   http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
  });
}))); Works pretty well combined with TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting()).configureTestingModule. Though it can only be called once (So not more than 1 test is possible). The karma-test-shim.js is calling those functions as well. But with no effect. I didn't figure out the why, yet.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the `AsyncTestCompleter`, and I've never seen it used anywhere, except in the Angular source tests. I don't know if it's something that's just meant to be used internally or not, but when I tested I got a different error, saying there is no provider for `AsyncTestCompleter`.

For your test though, you don't need to use it. There are other ways to handle async tests. One options is to just use `async`

```
import { async } from '@angular/core/testing'

it('...', async(inject([Http], (http) => {
   http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
  });
})));
```

Here, we don't need to call `done` anywhere. The test gets wrapped in Zone, and the Zone is aware of all asynchronous tasks, and waits for them to complete before ending the test.

Anther option is `fakeAsync` where we can force the to wait the ending of tasks *synchronously* by calling `tick`

```
import { fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core';

it('...', fakeAsync(inject([Http], (http) => {
  let data;
  http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    data = res.text();
  });
  tick();
  expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
})));
```

The other option is to just use the native Jasmine `done`. I am not sure how to get it to work with `inject` though, so you can just get the `Http` just like you are currently doing from the test bed.

```
it('...', fakeAsync((done) => {
  http.request('data.json').subscribe((res) => {
    expect(res.text()).toBe('awesome');
    done();
  });
}));
```

This is all explained in the docs you linked to, in the section [Test a component with an async service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-async-service)

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer brought me closer to a solution. One problem was that I didn't call: TestBed.initTestEnvironment(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, platformBrowserDynamicTesting()).configureTestingModule in my test.